# Esconder um elemento do v-for com v-show

Tags: vue.js-2

Preciso esconder um elemento do v-for com o v-show.

Tenho uma lista que popula um menu e preciso esconder um determinado elemento, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Mostre o código que já tem.

Comment: <router-link v-for="(link,index) in sidebarLinks" :to="link.path" tag="li" :ref="link.name" :key="link.name + index">
          <a>
            <i :class="link.icon"></i>

            <p>{{link.name}}</p>
          </a>
        </router-link>

Comment: Utilize o link [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/263862/edit) para adicionar informações à pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que seja só você acrescentar dentro de cada object link um boolean com a condição para exibir o elemento.

```
<router-link v-for="(link,index) in sidebarLinks" v-show="link.CODICAO_PARA_EXIBIR_ELEMENTO" :to="link.path" tag="li" :ref="link.name" :key="link.name + index">
    <a>
        <i :class="link.icon"></i>
        <p>{{link.name}}</p>
    </a>
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi, diferentemente do Angular, por exemplo, o Vue aceita duas diretivas no mesmo elemento:

```
<button v-for="(letra, indice) in letras" 
    @click="inserirLetra(letra, indice)"
    v-show="botoesRemovidos.indexOf(indice) < 0">
    {{ letra }}
</button>
```

Então é super simples.

Este exemplo que estou te mostrando, eu mesmo que utilizei no projeto [anagramador](https://github.com/jtpdev/anagramador-vue) que faz parte do livro [Vue: uma abordagem prática](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BL4JSSF).

Espero ter ajudado!